# What do you call someone who always needs to be mentally or physically active?

Tags: meaning

What do you call a person that can't just relax, someone who always needs to be working or taking a class or working out? Someone who can sit still in one place but only if they are working on something (mentally), and if they aren't working on something mentally then they need to be physically doing something, like running errands or working out etc.. BUT the specific person I have in mind is very calm, and patient but they cannot sit around doing nothing because they feel lazy, like time is wasted.

Maybe it would help to point out that there is not a physical drive to do these things, it isn't a energy level but more of a psychological need to do these things. Often this person is somewhat tired and usually doesn't get a full nights sleep due to over them being so busy with everything they try to do.

Comment: That description makes me think of hiper-activity.

Comment: Hyperactive would be my choice.

Comment: @JohnClifford  Such a person is DEFINITELY NOT [hyperactive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_deficit_hyperactivity_disorder). *Hyperactivity* is associated with the neurodevelopmental condition, often known as ADHD, which in severe cases can be very distressing. (I once knew someone whose young boy was literally awake, and moving around, for 23 hours in every 24). I don't think that is the sort of thing the OP had in mind. I would suggest that person is a *physically very active person*, but well within normal limits.

Comment: The main definition of hyperactive is "unusually or abnormally active" which I think does fit here. You can't link me to an associated mental condition as a definition of a word that doesn't mean the same thing. :P

Comment: @John Clifford My point is that *hyperactive* is a clinical term, so ought not to be used in an everyday sense. A doctor or a clinician is the only person who can diagnose hyperactivity. So one ought not to use it unless there has been a diagnosis. Margaret Thatcher used only to have about 4 hours sleep a night and was working, speaking, meeting, and moving around the rest of the time. I have never heard it said she was *hyperactive*.

Comment: @Soudabeh *Workaholic* is another of those clinical terms - a bit like *hyperactive*. You will see from the dictionary definition that it says *compulsively*. The majority of people who are said to be *workaholics* are nothing of the sort. There is a terrible tendency in modern society to pathologise people's personalities with words like this.

Comment: @WS2 I don't know if it's a cultural thing but I've never considered hyperactive a purely clinical term; my parents used to say I was hyperactive as a kid because I couldn't sit still, but +1 anyway.

Comment: @Soudabeh: no it's not *"workaholic"*. They question merely said "needs to stay active", it didn't say anything about it being work-related. Doing crosswords or playing the piano is hyperactive but not workaholic (for most of us).

Comment: @smci, Yes,  you are right. :) I deleted my comment.

Comment: @WS2: perhaps, and more so in the US, even pathologically so, but *hyperactive* has already been common (non-psychobabble) parlance throughout the English-speaking world for decades now [[proof: see Google Trends graph](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=hyperactive)]. Unlike say 'ADHD' or ['cognitive impairment'](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=cognitive%20impairment)

Answer (score 6):

There is `type-A personality`, `restless`, `ADHD`, or just `hyper`.

**Edit:**

Three of these terms were originally medical diagnoses.

"Type-A personality" was a theory developed by the cardiologist [Meyer Friedman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meyer_Friedman) that the behavior of chronically angry and impatient people raises their risk of heart attacks.  The underlying theory remains controversial but the phrase and the concept have passed into the popular culture.

"ADHD" stands for Attention Deficit/Hyperactivity Disorder ("hyper" is just short for "hyperactive").  The disorder itself is a highly controversial diagnosis about the social behavior of children, especially boys, but again the phrase and the concept are now part of the culture, at least partially detached from the medical judgment.

There is a fair amount of controversy in the comments for this answer about the use of "ADHD" as a label for a certain kind of person (the  criticism was unleveled against "Type-A" and "hyper", but it would be equally valid).

Without discussing the factual statements, I would advise: give it up.  The label for any psychological or social pathology is liable to being appropriated to describe personality quirks that vaguely resemble the problem, e.g. "retarded", "spastic", "schizophrenic", "paranoid", "catatonic", even plain old "crazy".  I don't think there is any way to stop the process, and dodging it just puts you on the famous Euphemism Treadmill.

Comment: I believe ADHD also includes short attention spans and one can be hyperactive and still be able to focus for long periods.

Comment: I like the use of *restless*. That is probably the word the OP wants. But please see my comment on the matter of ADHD and hyperactivity. These are clinical disorders which names are heavily overused - often by parents to describe their normal healthy children who are just above average in physical energy and bounce.

Comment: Type A Personality, and restless seem to be the sort of thing I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @SaraCosta - It is something of a misconception that ADHD implies a "short attention span".  In fact, one common trait of ADHD is "hyperfocus", where the individual cannot be distracted from a task but focuses on it intensely.

Comment: ("Type-A" is probably the best term for the described person.  It's something of a neutral term (not pejorative), it's commonly (and reasonably consistently) understood, and it avoids dipping into clinical terms.)

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but it needs more explanation. You should be especially clear that ADHD is formal medical diagnosis, and not all hyperactive people are necessarily ADHD.

Comment: @Hot Licks: ADHD = Attention deficit hyperactivity disorder; the attention deficit part being what I meant as short attention span. As a child (way before the ADHD term was popular) I was diagnosed as hyperactive but there was no reference to my ability to focus.

Comment: @SaraCosta - Trust me, I know what ADHD is.

Answer (score 0):

What about **ebullient**, i.e. overflowing with fervor, enthusiasm, or excitement; showing liveness and vivacity; cheerful and full of energy.

Comment: No, that's about personality and extroversion, not about activity level. There are introverts who are hyperactive, yet noone would ever call them ebullient. I personally know lots of them. As to cheerfulness, depressive people can be hyperactive too.